# Unable to using Terminix

Tags: command-line

I can no longer use Terminix. I remember that last thing I did in Terminix it was setting own command (`echo`) with option immediately closing terminal. Since then, Terminix always starts and ends at the same time.

What can I do in this situation? I started `uninstall.sh` script from [GitHub's Terminix site](https://github.com/gnunn1/terminix) but after reinstall it is exactly the same situation.

Command `whereis terminix` shows me that Terminix is in `/usr/bin/terminix` and in `/usr/share/terminix` but remove these locations by `rm -rf` nothing changes. I have Ubuntu 16.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Re-installing the program doesn't affect the program settings stored in the user profile.

Since Terminix' settings are configured through GSettings, you can reset the responsible configuration option `com.gexperts.Terminix.use-custom-command` either through the `dconf-editor` GUI or the `gsettings` terminal command:

```
gsettings reset com.gexperts.Terminix use-custom-command
```

(I don't have Terminix installed but I read its [GSettings schema definition](https://github.com/gnunn1/terminix/blob/1.0.0/data/gsettings/com.gexperts.Terminix.gschema.xml).)

Answer (score -1):

Presumably, you added the `echo` command using some kind of GUI menu offered by this Terminix program. The simplest way to remove that is to rename its configuration directory. I don't have Terminix installed, so I can't be sure, but it should be either:

```
~/.config/terminix
```

or

```
~/.terminix
```

So, just run

```
mv ~/config/terminix ~/config/terminix.old
mv ~/.terminix ~/.terminix.old
```

One of the two should work and will rename your existing Terminix configuration directory. All your settings will be lost but you should now be able to open it again.